# how to post data to second form after login in php curl

Tags: php, curl

There is a login form.
After successfully manual login, there will be a information form to submit.
How I can fill it by curl in php or other tools? because the login form must be submitting manual and when I fetch the page by curl in new tab in browser, the session not detected and the login form display again.

is any way to do it?

Edit:

I konow my curl code needs to detect browser cookies, so I use [this add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/export-cookies/)
to export cookies to a file called "cookies.txt" and add this 2 lines to my script:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");

but problem not solved yet.

is any other way? or my solotion is incorrect? or the way of include browser cookies in curl is incorrect?

Comment: You need to get the session cookie from your browser, and include that in the cookies that you send with `curl`.

Comment: how? can u show me sample codes?